# Sometimes quill editor show '?' in the display

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-quill

While creating template in quill editor sometime it shows ? in the display of content.i think its due to space, or might be something else.Suggest some ideas to resolved it.Its generate randomly

[sample image that shows error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uSbMQ.png)

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Answer (score -1):

Remove **Zero Width Character String** before passing to API

```
export const removeZeroWidthCharacters = (str = '') => {
    return str.replace(/[\u200B-\u200D\uFEFF]/g, '')
}

ex: const str = "ABCD EFGH"

that space contains maybe zero width characters(uFEFF)

So this method will remove white-space characters
    const finalString = removeZeroWidthCharacters(str)
    console.log(finalString) // ABCDEFGH
```